# AngularJS sorting for text inside custom controls and big numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Please refer below link

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fjkcg

html:

```
<section ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <span class="label">Ordered By: {{orderByField}}, Reverse Sort: {{reverseSort}}</span><br><br>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='firstName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
          First Name <span ng-show="orderByField == 'firstName'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></span>
          </a>
        </th>
        <th>
          <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='lastName'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
            Last Name <span ng-show="orderByField == 'lastName'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></span>
          </a>
        </th>
        <th>
          <a href="#" ng-click="orderByField='age'; reverseSort = !reverseSort">
          Age <span ng-show="orderByField == 'age'"><span ng-show="!reverseSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseSort">v</span></span>
          </a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="emp in data.employees|orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort">
        <td>{{emp.firstName}}</td>
        <td> <input type="text"
                    ng-init="empx['name_'+$index]=emp['lastName']" 
          ng-model="empx['name_'+$index]"/> </td>
        <td>{{emp.age}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  //$scope.orderByField = 'firstName';
  $scope.reverseSort = false;
  $scope.empx={};
  $scope.data = {
    employees: [{
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'F',
      age: '6703114'
    },{
      firstName: 'Frank',
      lastName: 'D',
      age: '665087589'
    },{
      firstName: 'Sue',
      lastName: 'F',
      age: '5271761234'
    },
               {
      firstName: 'Sue',
      lastName: 'F',
      age: '52'
    },{
      firstName: 'Sue',
      lastName: 'F',
      age: '2334564564564564564'
    }]
  };
});
```

We have textbox controls and datepicker controls inside ng-repeat. when i do filter on lastname that is not sorting properly. how can i sort the collection which is inside the controls. Age  and lastname sort is not working,lastname sort not working because of the value is inside the textbox control and age not working because of large number but it was denoted as string. how i can achieve the sorting to be working properly in all cases.

Comment: your code pen just works fine ! I dont see any issue ? did your sorted it out ?

Comment: @Angular_10 lastName and age sort not working

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because ng-init. You should never use ng-init, except nested ng-repeats.

Try to remove ng-init and use clone( or original) of your employees data directly -

```
empx = data.employees.map(item => angular.extend({}, item));
```

and iterate over empx using `ng-model="item.lastName"` in template

Comment: I am not sure about your solution.how  i can solve this problem

Comment: please provide the fiddle